# Reading Info.plist from UITests in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ui-testing

Is it possible to read from the `Info.plist` file which is within the `UITests` folder file while UITesting ? If so, how.

So far I have tried that:

```
if let url =  Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Info", withExtension: "plist"),
        let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) as? [String:Any] {
        print(myDict)
    }
```

Though, that returns some `plist` which is not event the one I have in my main project folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a special bundle for your test class that you will need to read (or inject). Try this out. Replace `OSTests` in the `Bundle(for:)` call below with the name of your XCTestCase subclass.

```
  func testExample() {
    let testBundle = Bundle(for: OSTests.self)
    if let url = testBundle.url(forResource: "Info", withExtension: "plist"),
      let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) as? [String:Any] {
      print(myDict)
    }
  }
```

Then you will need to make sure that the test bundle is copied into your test app. Select your test target. Disclose the Copy Bundle Resources section in the Build Phases tab. Click on the + icon and select your test target's Info.plist file.

[image]

Here are what my results looked like then.
[image]